# Declaring a static constant in Java will affect the compiled class

Tags: java, static, constants

Ok here's my doubt...

I have a blazeDS (tomcat) application with some classes, each Class use the `Config` and `DB` Class for configuration and DB connection...

Here's an example of

`Config`Class

```
public class Config {
    public static final String DBClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    public static final String ConnectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/xe";
    public static final String UserDB = "user";
    public static final String PasswordDB = "pass"; 
}
```

`DB` Class

```
public class DB
{       
    public DB() {}

    public static Connection dbConnect(Connection c)
    {
                try
                {      if (c == null || c.isClosed()){                                  
                            Class.forName(Config.DBClass);
                            c = DriverManager.getConnection(Config.ConnectString,Config.UserDB,Config.PasswordDB);
                        }
                return c;                        
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException
    {
        if (!connection.isClosed())
            connection.close();
    }
}
```

I have a test and production environment, with different user/password per DB access..
I noticed that when updating the production file with the test classes (I do not overwrite the `Config.class`), I got error from DB...

So, are the `static final` values (user/pass) in compiled version saved directly in the class itself (in my case DB.class)???

Comment: "I do not overwrite the Config.class"  --> I guess you mean that you **are** overwriting Config.class and not DB.class

Comment: Next to the question at hand: DB configs are better maintained in configuration files than "hard coded"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes.

An excerpt from the [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf):

> "References
>   to fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are resolved at
>   compile-time to the constant value that is denoted. No reference to
>   such a field should be present in the code in a binary file (except in
>   the class or interface containing the field, which will have code to
>   initialize it). Such a field must always appear to have been
>   initialized (§12.4.2); the default initial value for the type of such
>   a field must never be observed. See §13.4.9 for a discussion." (p.
>   339)

Comment: "So, are the static final values (user/pass) in compiled version saved directly in the class itself (in my case DB.class)?" Yes, if they are compile-time initialized primitives (thus being constants: "A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable"), and that is the case, the values will be compiled directly into DB.class.

Answer (score 0):

> So, are the static final values (user/pass) in compiled version saved
>   directly in the class itself (in my case DB.class)???

Yes, any final variable is replaced by its literal value in the byte code.

Answer (score 0):

static final variabes (constants) which are "Compile time Constants" are inlined at their destination.

so if you use the constant in several classes those classes are affected. if you for some reason don't deploy all the affected classes bad things happen and your old values are still used.